# HTML5 Quintus button click doesn't work in local

Tags: html5, quintus-engine

If you try to run this example http://html5quintus.com/docs/ui.html, you'll be able to click the buttons, but you won't if you download a local copy of the example and click the index file (without using a web server).

I know I need to run the code in a web server and not by just double clicking on the files when I have a .json file, but I can't understand the reason why also the click doesn't work (it does not require resource loading).

Maybe there's a simple modify I can apply to the example code or to the libs to make it work... Any suggestion? Thank you!

EDIT

I don't see any JS error:

[image: Quintus doesn't show errors...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The example in http://html5quintus.com/docs/ui.html relies on a previous version of the engine. With the newer (the one you can download from gitHub) it doesn't work... To fix the example look at this issue segnalation: https://github.com/cykod/Quintus/issues/102.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Developer Tools in your favourite browser to diagnose your problems.

In this particular example, file tries to load JS files, as well as images, and if image wont be loaded it will throw an exception:

```
Uncaught Error Loading: enemy.png quintus.js:1782
```

Which stops JS execution, that is why nothing is coming up. But if you use Web Server with all media it requires - it will be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please look at my edit. Anyway it doesn't work even with a local web server. Maybe is related to Firefox (I use v27.0.1)...

Comment: Please check network tab if everything is loaded well. I've downloaded everything and it works well even from file.

Comment: I found the problem... There was a breaking change in the new engine and the example was not updated. Thank you.